# SQL Server and Android

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, android

Is there any way to connect to a SQL Server from an Android application and execute/query SQL statements without Web Service/WCF etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) is a library written in C and available under LGPL, which allows one to connect to MSSQL and Sybase servers. I don't think anyone has tried that, but I don't see why it shouldn't compile on Android NDK. Then you can wrap it into JNI classes, and use it from your Android app.

Comment: Can the person who downmodded me kindly explain the reasoning in a comment?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Last I checked, Android doesn't support JDBC (and there were no custom drivers) so you can't make connections straight from Androi to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jtds driver (version 1.25) to connect to an external sql server